# Why am I getting duplicate of entities when I updating an existing entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I save some data to my database and Im using code first. Everything works fine until I want to change an entity. For example: I add four persons to the database, and when I updating one of them the database adds duplicates of all persons.

**UPDATE**
The problem will be in this code:

```
Conversation newConv = new Conversation { Name = chatPerson.Name };
        newConv.Members.Add(person);
        newConv.Members.Add(chatPerson);
```

`Conversation` has a list of `Members` and when Im trying to add `Members` to the list then I will get my duplicate in the database.

**OLD POST**

The first thing I do is to load one person:

```
var person = repo.GetWholePerson(3);
```

Code that returns the person:

```
public Person GetWholePerson(int id)
    {
        return _ctx.Persons
            .Include(a => a.Colleagues)
            .Include(a => a.Conversations)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    }
```

Here is the code that saves to database:

```
using (Repository<Person> repo = new Repository<Person>())
    {
       var per = repo.Get(person.Id);
       var chatPer = repo.Get(chatPerson.Id);

       per.Conversations.Add(newConv);
       chatPer.Conversations.Add(newConv);

       repo.Update(per);
       repo.Update(chatPer);
    }
```

And here is the code in the Repository:

```
public void Update(T entity)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Colleagues { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Test { get; set; }


    public Person()
    {
        Conversations = new List<Conversation>();
        Colleagues = new List<Person>();
        Test = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Conversation class:

```
public class Conversation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }

    public Conversation()
    {
        Messages = new List<Message>();
        Members = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine! But when I connecting to my database there are four new persons. =(

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the `Attach` method, it will mark the entity in the `Unchanged` state, which means it has not changed since it was attached to the context. Objects that you are attaching are assumed to exist in the database. `Attach()` is really useful for updating entities in a scenario like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
   context.Attach(person);
   person.Name = "Bob";
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database and you want to save all the changes that you did before, just call the `Entry` method modifying the entity state:

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    _ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

When you change the state to `Modified`, all the properties of the entity will be marked as modified and all the property values will be sent to the database when `SaveChanges` is called.

In fact, if you are using the same instance of `repo` to get and modify your entity, I think  you don't even need to call the `Entry` method, just call the `SaveChanges` method.

If you want to know more how work these methods, take a look this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your post, I have updated my post. I would be glad if you take a look at it.